# How to apply tooltip class for all children in angular?

Tags: angular, tooltip

I have a group of buttons with tooltips. Currently I'm setting the tooltip class for each as below. I'm wondering if there is a way to set the tooltip class once, without replicating it for every button.
Setting it in the parent doesn't work.

```
<div class="the-parent">
  <img src="icon1" matTooltip="Tip 1" matTooltipClass="my-tooltip-class"/>
  <img src="icon2" matTooltip="Tip 2" matTooltipClass="my-tooltip-class"/>
   ....
  <img src="iconn" matTooltip="Tip n" matTooltipClass="my-tooltip-class"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem and I don't think you can set it in the parent like you mentioned.

However, I would use an `*ngFor` for this (to loop over same things in the HTML). Check out `*ngFor` [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/)

Component

```
iconData = [
    { src: 'icon1', matTooltip: 'Tip 1' }, 
    { src: 'icon2', matTooltip: 'Tip 2' },
    .....
    { src: 'iconn', matTooltip: 'Tip n' },
]
```

HTML

```
<img *ngFor="let icon of iconData"
     [src]="icon.src"
     [matTooltip]="icon.matTooltip"
     matTooltipClass="my-tooltip-class" />
```